# How to pass multiple ref to forwardRef using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my code and currently works. 
It detects the width of the component - Table, and then sets that width on the Wrapper.

### Wrapper

```js
import React from 'react';

type shapeWrapper = {
  filtered: string[]
};

type shapeState = {
  tableWidth: string,
  visibility: string
};

class Wrapper extends Component<shapeWrapper, shapeState> {
  private refParent = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
  public ref = React.createRef<HTMLTableElement>();

// replace above with 
/*
public refTable = React.createRef<HTMLTableElement>(),
public refTds:HTMLTableElement[] = filtered.map(item => React.createRef<HTMLTableElement>());
public ref = {
  refTable,
  refTds
}
*/


  constructor(props: shapeWrapper) {
    super(props);
    this.setWrapperWidth = this.setWrapperWidth.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      tableWidth: '0',
      visibility: 'hidden'
    };
  }
  setWrapperWidth(tableWidth:string) {
    this.setState({
      tableWidth,
      visibility: 'visible'
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {filtered} = this.props;
    const {tableWidth} = this.state;
    const {setWrapperWidth} = this;
    const {ref, refParent} = this;
    return (
      <section ref={refParent} style={{width: tableWidth}}>
        <Table
          filtered={filtered}
          ref={ref}
          onMount={tableWidth => {setWrapperWidth(tableWidth);}}
        />
      </section>
    );
  }
};
export default Wrapper;
```

### Table

```js
import React, {forwardRef, useEffect} from 'react';
export type shapeTable = {
  filtered: string[][],
  onMount: (tableWidth:string) => void
};

type Ref = HTMLTableElement;

const Table = forwardRef<Ref, shapeTable>(({filtered, onMount}, ref) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if(ref && typeof ref !== 'function' && ref.current) {
      const tableWidth:string = window.getComputedStyle(ref.current).getPropertyValue("width");
      onMount(tableWidth);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return filtered.length
    ? (
        <table ref={ref}>
          <tr >
            {filtered.map((item, ind) => (
               <th>{item}</th>
             ))}
          </tr>
        </table>
    )
  : null
});

export default Table;
```

What I want to do is now detect the widths of the td columns. 
I need to provide multiple refs, but all my attempts seem to fail. Typescript is expecting the past ref to always be the target, and not an array.  How do I pass and receive it on the forwardRef at the other end:
This is an example of what I want to do but typescript does not expect 'ref' to be an object let alone an array.

```
public refTable = React.createRef<HTMLTableElement>(),
public refTds:HTMLTableElement[] = filtered.map(item => React.createRef<HTMLTableElement>());
public ref = {
  refTable,
  refTds
}
```